# How to in execute Google API into Nativescript-Vue?

Tags: vue.js, nativescript

Can anyone help me how to use Google APIs into Nativescript-Vue. Please, Thanks in advance

Comment: you should ask for specific API, as Google has many API. so which api you want to use?

Comment: ahhmm sorry, Google Distance API sir

Answer (score 0):

You may try with `axios`.
If you hit this api by axios

> `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?units=imperial&origins=Washington,DC&destinations=New+York+City,NY&key=YOUR_API_KEY`

you will get data like this -

```
{
"destination_addresses" : [ "New York, NY, USA" ],
"origin_addresses" : [ "Washington, DC, USA" ],
"rows" : [
  {
     "elements" : [
        {
           "distance" : {
              "text" : "225 mi",
              "value" : 361715
           },
           "duration" : {
              "text" : "3 hours 49 mins",
              "value" : 13725
           },
           "status" : "OK"
        }
     ]
  }
],
"status" : "OK"
}
```

so it's easy with `vuejs` for show data in view, if you familiar with `vuejs`.

> Happy coding :)

Comment: Unfortunately sir, i cant use axios in Nativescript-Vue. or is there a way to use axios to it?

Comment: bro, you can use `axios` , i am using it and it's working perfectly. 1. first install `npm install axios --save`. 2. `import axois from 'axios'` 3. `axios.get().then()`;